# traceroute, only print gateway information

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, traceroute

I can't find any info regarding this in the man-pages. How would one go about only printing the gateway using traceroute?

Comment: would you clarify the question? it is not entirely clear what your need is. Maybe an example?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Basically I'm looking for a way to use traceroute to only print one line. That line being the one containing the gateway information, nothing else.

Comment: anything against netstat -nr? I think what you want with traceroute can be done, will check it out and will come back.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I appreciate your help. Nothing against netstat -nr. It's only that it's a school assignment that requires me to use traceroute. I've read the man-pages but haven't found a flag that does what I want, apparently it is possible though.

Comment: You should read about e.g. `grep`, `sed` and `awk` and how they can be used to cut out lines from `traceroute`'s output.

Comment: @dessert Yeah, grep would work. But the question eludes to there being a flag for traceroute to only print the gateway. Which has me confused since I can't see anything in the man-pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `traceroute` you've to enter maximum `hop` as 1 using `m1` option as follows.

```
traceroute -m1 google.com
```

According to basic rules of computer network Gateway and host must be connected to same `NIC` of router. Otherwise Data Link Layer will unable to deliver packets from hosts to Gateway. So it's `hop` should be 1.

So by setting maximum hop as one and tracing any host will prit Gateway only.

Comment: indeed, you beat me to it ; as an additional curiosity, the max limit is 64 hops.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for your time! And thank you @RuiFRibeiro for you help too!

Comment: Really good question.. Liked it

Comment: You can pipe the output with     | awk '/2  / { print $2 }'  to print only the gateway ip